# CComPtr replacement for gcc?

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers

I'm doing some COM programming and my compiler is gcc. That means CComPtr is not available for me. How can I easily implement a replacement by using Boost? The semantics I need are:

- Call `AddRef` when copied
- Call `Release` when destructed
- Extra: be able to tell if the object it points to is still valid (not sure if this is possible)

I think it might be possible to use `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter, but I'm not very familiar with those features (I also don't know how to make it call `AddRef` and `Release`). I know I can hand-craft this class, but I'm pretty sure that this functionality is available in Boost in a generalized form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the HILO project, it rolls it's own CComPtr implementation.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it does (although, with a weird/buggy behavior: it increments the COM refcount in its constructor, which means the user has to call `Release` on the raw pointer at some point, otherwise there will be a leak). I modified it to fit my needs. For anyone wondering, here is the link to the [HILO project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Hilo).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the semantics of the required functions `AddRef` and `Release` are, but:

You can use `boost::intrusive_ptr` and have two free functions `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` and `intrusive_ptr_release` that will be called to increase/decrease a reference counter. Those can then possibly be calling those `AddRef` and `Release` functions on your object. You have to take care of deletion yourself when the counter reaches `0`.

Comment: This is also a correct answer. I chose the other one because it's simpler for me to use that than intrusive_ptr.